# JAVA email message - clip quoted lines

Tags: java, regex, email

is there a JAVA library to clip the quoted text from an email message?

If it's an HTML message, I used an HTML parser so far and removed the blockquotes from the DOM tree but I have more trouble with the plain text format.

I tried regex:

```
    emailBody = emailBody.replaceAll("\n>[^\n]*?\n", "\n");
```

but I'm far from mastering it, so I though there has to be a solution since it's a problem concerning more people I guess.
The code above replaces all lines which are new lines (after \n) and beginning with >, not containing any other new lines as long as there is other content and ending with \n. Also I think replacement should be done from starting from the end of the message, and so on. It's a bit more complicated than just that line of code.

So any help is welcome!

Cheers,
Balázs

Comment: I'm pretty sure Java Mail (javax.mail.*) will give you the text of an email without having to do any parsing etc.

Comment: but the qouted text is part of the email body, so it won't clip it by default. would you show me an example please?

Comment: Ah sorry, I misunderssod what you meant by "quoted"

Comment: quoted-printable maybe? :) that head-ache is already gone. a week ago :]

Answer (score 1):

Do I get you right that you consider each line that starts with a `>` char a *quoted line*?

Here's a quick solution:

```
String[] lines = emailBody.split("\n");
StringBuilder clippedEmailBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for (String line:lines)
  if (!line.startsWith(">"))
     clippedEmailBuilder.append(line);
emailBody = clippedEmailBuilder.toString();
```

Comment: Well, almost. I want to replace the quoted lines (beginning with >) at the end of the message but if somebody does inline quoting-answering then I won't replace that. But to use StringBuilder is a good idea. I think I'm gonna start at the end end if there's a line which does not begin with >, the loop stops.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with your RE, but considering every line starting with '>' to be quoted mail text you can filter them out with the following:

```
emailBody.replaceAll(">.*\n", "")
```

This will match every line starting with '>' and replace it (including the newline) with an empty string

Comment: yes, but . could include \n as well, so that's why the [^n] in my expression. But the starting point of mine was also your code. The problem with that is that if there's a > at any point in the message, it will replace the whole text from that point.

Comment: Right, sloppy on my part. This should do it better then Pattern.compile("^>.*\n", Pattern.MULTILINE).matcher(emailBody).replaceAll(""); Thought it won't coven the case with inline commenting no getting clipped. I think you'll need a non regexp solution for that